# Spring MVC - ServletRequestDataBinder to automatically create instances of nested properties

Tags: spring-mvc

Consider a class (an ORM entity):

```
public class MyEntity {
    Long id;
    MyOtherEntity assoc;
    // ... getters and setters
}
```

I want for it to be bound automatically in a Spring MVC controller, something like that:

```
public ModelAndView method(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response, MyEntity command) {
}
```

It works well for simple properties like id, but for `assoc` it throws an exception `NullValueInNestedPathException`, since `assoc` wasn't instantiated by constructor. The question is, how can I tell `ServletRequestDataBinder` (or `BeanWrapper` or anything) to instantiate properties automatically as it makes its way through the nested property path?

I could of course make another class derived from `MyEntity` and put an instantiation in it, but then I won't be able to save it using simple Hibernate call, since derived class won't be mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, one way to do that in case of `MultiActionController` is to override `newCommandObject`; but I would like a more generic solution.